# C# SetValue TargetException Object Does not match target type

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm with a problem that I simply cannot solve, I've been researching for hours but with no results. Please help!

What I'm trying to do:

I have a User Control that list a class on my form and I want it to make changes on the main form if someone selects a different item on the list.

So I created an event:

```
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Object item = this.List.GetType().GetProperty("Item").GetValue(this.List, new Object[] { listBox1.SelectedIndex });

            Control a = this.TopLevelControl;
            Object temp = a.GetType().GetProperty("currentExpression").GetValue( a, null );

            a.GetType().GetProperty("currentExpression").SetValue(temp, item, null);


        }
    }
```

In this code 'a' holds the main form. ( And this event runs in the User Control) So I have all that I need.

The List object is a List of Expressions. And the currentExpression property on the Main form is a Expression.

I want to put the Expression ( which I called item ) on the property currentExpression ( which is a Expression on the MainForm). But it allways says "Object does not match target type." TargetException was unhandled

When I debug I can see that both of them are correct. ( temp and item ) But it still throws an exception.

EDIT:

I must say that, the "List" object is not a `List<Something>`, it is the object to be listed, so List is an object ( object List ). My user control is generic, Thats why I'm using reflection.

This way I can have  objectList1.ShowList(ListExpressions, "OriginalExpression");

where is this case ListExpressions is a List, but is sent to the user control as a object. Through reflection I can check which type of List it is and then read the property "OriginalExpression" and display a list.

So I'm gonna have a list of the property "OriginalExpression".

The User Control works fine, the problem is making this last part work. When I click on an item I get that message "Object does not match target type.".

Any ideas on how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you debug what is the Type of each.. regardless if you can see the both.. the error pretty much explains what the issue is ...

Comment: Can you show what exactly is the definition of this List? And why do you need reflections at all?

Comment: Sorry I could not answer earlier, The list object is not a necessary a LIST it is the object to be listed so List is an object ( object list ). My user control is generic, Thats why I'm using reflection.

Does this makes sense or I should consider another implementation?

Comment: This way I can have  objectList1.ShowList(ListExpressions, "OriginalExpression");

So I'm gonna have a list of the property "OriginalExpression".

Comment: I solved the problem, It's not exacly what I was looking for but it is working,

I changed the "Control a = this.TopLevelControl;" to "mainForm a = (mainForm)this.TopLevelControl;"

And the "a.GetType().GetProperty("currentExpression").SetValue(temp, (NCalc.Expression)item, null);" to "a.currentExpression = ( NCalc.Expression )item;"

That solved my problem because I'm avoid reflection. 

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem,

It's not exacly what I was looking for, but it is working!

I changed the

```
Control a = this.TopLevelControl;
```

to

```
mainForm a = (mainForm)this.TopLevelControl;
```

And the

```
a.GetType().GetProperty("currentExpression").SetValue(temp, (NCalc.Expression)item, null);
```

to

```
a.currentExpression = ( NCalc.Expression )item;
```

That solved my problem because I'm avoiding reflection. Thanks guys! –

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do all this with reflection? You don't say anything about that.

It looks like a complex way of writing:

```
var item = this.List[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

var a = this.TopLevelControl;
var temp = a.currentExpression;

temp.currentExpression = item; // ???
```

except that the last line (which i marked `???`) looks strange since you `GetType()` on your `a`, find a property `currentExpression` from the type from `a`, and then use **`temp`** as the instance on which to set the property (set to `item`). Here's the line from your question I'm talking about:

```
a.GetType().GetProperty("currentExpression").SetValue(temp, item, null);
```

Comment: I have a user control for that fills a list box given a List of objects.

Comment: Sorry I could not answer earlier,

The list object is not a necessary a LIST it is the object to be listed so List is an object  ( object list ). My user control is generic, Thats why I'm using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement it this way:

```
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 )
        {
            var item = this.List.Item[listBox1.SelectedIndex];

            var mainControl = this.TopLevelControl as IExpressionProvider;

            if ( mainControl != null )
                mainControl.CurrentExpression = item;
        }
    }
```

and in your main form just implement this simple interface:

```
public interface IExpressionProvider
{
    YourExpressionType CurrentExpression { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I could not answer earlier, The list object is not a necessary a LIST it is the object to be listed so List is an object ( object list ). My user control is generic, Thats why I'm using reflection.